# How to remove a line from a file without overwriting the contents in a new file

Tags: c#, file, c#-4.0, file-io, c#-3.0

```
FileName="1.pdf",filepath="f:/test1"
FileName="2.pdf",filepath="f:/test2"
FileName="3.pdf",filepath="f:/test3"
FileName="4.pdf",filepath="f:/test4"
FileName="5.pdf",filepath="f:/test5"
FileName="6.pdf",filepath="f:/test6"
```

I don't want to create a new file. Overwriting in a same file is ok

I tried the following.

```
var reader = File.OpenText("f:/test5");
reader. // ?
```

I don't know what to put after reader. If any alternate way is there, provide me a solution.I want to remove only a particular line based on the unique file name. If I am having 5.pdf as the filename, then I need to delete or remove the entire line which is "FileName="5.pdf"...line from the file. I don't want to overwrite the contents in a new file again. Provide me a solution. Thanks.

Comment: why you don't whant to ovewrite into a new file. ?

Comment: What do you want exactly? remove a line from a file without writing the file... it makes no sense... What is the expected result? A file on disk, an enumerator on lines ?

Comment: I don't want to create a new file. Overwriting in a same file is ok.

Comment: You cannot reomve a line from a textfile without rewriting the file. The best you can do, is to rewrite from the position of the removed line by usiung a Seek(), but you will have to rewrite the following lines.

Comment: may be you should consider using a erased tag/character and implement a reader that ignores lines beginning with this character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reomve a line from a textfile without rewriting the file. Do something like this

```
string filename =
   Path.Combine(
       Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory),
       "Test1.txt");

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
var list = new List<string>(lines);
list.RemoveAt(4);
File.WriteAllLines(filename, list.ToArray());
```

---

EDIT:

You can find a line with a specific filename like this:

```
int index = list.FindIndex(s => s.EndsWith("/test5\""));
// Or whatever test is appropriate.

if (index >= 0) {
    list.RemoveAt(index);
    File.WriteAllLines(filename, list.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: When I am executing the last line File.WriteAllLines(filename, list.ToArray()); error message displays as "Access is denied". I am having administrator rights.Help me.Thanks.

Comment: Access is probably denied, because the file is still open in another application. Close the other application. Note: I have tested the code example. It works for me.

Comment: File is opened but I have closed now. Again it is showing message as "Access to the path 'C:\Test1.txt' is denied." Thanks.

Comment: The root directory is protected in newer windows versions. Try another one. E.g. `string filename = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "Test1.txt");`

Comment: Now I tried in F:. It is working fine as expected. Thank You very much. Great.

Comment: Can I able to remove particular line based on the filename giving as in my question instead of giving line number. Thanks

Comment: Thank You very much. Working very fine as expected. Great.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using gnu tools, you can use sed http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1451-sed-delete-one-or-more-lines-from-a-file

Comment: First, make sure you have sed available (type sed from the command line and see if its a recognized command).  If not, install gnu tools (I'm assuming you're on windows) http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/. Then use a call like system("sed /FileName=""5\.pdf""/d f:/test1") or use the System.Diagnostics.Process class.

Answer (score 0):

It's technically impossible, as much as I'm aware of, as OS will create a new IO artifact.(*By the way not very sure on this*) .

But what is much more important, that it's *extremely* dangerous. IO operations are subjects to fail, so you have to gurantee in some way **consistency** of your operations on file.

One of possible ways of doing this is:

- write all lines, except those ones you want to skip, into the new TEMP file
- rename your old file with some other temp name
- rename fisrt TEMP file in name of previous file
- delete original file.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what utility you use or what code you write, the operating system will always create a new file to do it.